# create .msi or setup file in C# 2010

Tags: c#

How can I create either .msi file or setup file from the application I have created in VC# 2010. Please help me.

Comment: Yes i have tried with "Setup and deployment" but it is still blank project...

Comment: @fawad And did you read the documentation for Setup and deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Setup project in [Visual Studio 2010-Creating a Setup Project and adding File Types.mp4 - YouTube .](http://bit.ly/L1E0NE)

Answer (score 1):

In the same solution as your executable package, create a "Setup" project

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Deployment Tasks and Walkthroughs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/206sadcd) in msdn is very useful.